# AddressBook in background thead: weird intermittent crash

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I'm reading Address Book in a background thread and I'm getting some crash reports with the following stacktrace.

```
    0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 
__pthread_kill + 8
1    libsystem_c.dylib  
abort + 94
2    AppSupport 
abortAfterPassingIntegrityCheck + 38
3    AppSupport 
runIntegrityCheckAndAbort + 526
4    AppSupport 
checkResultWithStatement + 120
5    AppSupport 
CPSqliteStatementReset + 60
6    AddressBook    
_imageStoreHasFullSizeImageForRecord + 102
7    AddressBook    
ABCImageStoreHasImagesForRecordWithFormat + 48
8    AddressBook    
ABCImageStoreHasImagesForRecord + 14
9    AddressBook    
ABCPersonHasImageDataEntries + 186
10   AddressBook    
ABCPersonHasImageData + 10
11   AddressBook    
ABPersonHasImageData + 8
12   Brewster ✭  AddressBookHandler.m line 501
-[AddressBookHandler needToImportPhotoContacts] + 50
```

I can not replicate, so it only happens sometimes. This code is just trying to see if a ABPerson has an image. What could cause this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was seeing the same issue.  It appears to be because the ABAddressBookRef can only be used by a single thread.  Per ABAddressBookCreate documentation:

> Important You must ensure that an instance of ABAddressBookRef is used by only one thread.

There is another article that also references this issue: http://blog.byadrian.net/2012/05/05/ios-addressbook-framework-and-gcd/

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that ABAddressBookRef limitation. My guess is that even I was aware, I was still violating it somewhere. Thanks for the reply anyway! I'm gonna accept your answer for taking the time and replying even though this question has been here for a while.